# code-igniter text field auto complete from database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

i need code for autocompelte textfiled from database. i attach the code i used ?`
    
        Autocomplete Textbox Demo | PHP | jQuery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = <?php include('autocomplete.php'); ?>;
        $("#department_name").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            autoFocus:true
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Department Name</label></br>
    <input id="department_name" type="text" size="50" />
</body>
```

`

Comment: If you need code, you have to write it, we at SO can later fix it if it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Use remote datasource:

```
   $( "#department_name" ).autocomplete({
          source: "autocomplete.php",
          minLength: 3,
          select: function( event, ui ) {

          },
          close: function( event, ui ) {

          }
        });
```

Comment: need controller ,model , view page to access data from DB and autocomplete in text field